# What is the pgAgent service account?

Tags: postgresql, installation, postgresql-9.5, enterprisedb, pgagent

Im installing pgAgent using Stack Builder.

In one step ask me for service account. Should I use PC, Domain or DB user? Or create a new one?

I try using my `DOMAIN\my.user.name`  also using the postgres user and return same error.

I dont have the `PC_Name\Administrator` password

> User creation failed. The password specified is incorrect or length of the user name is longer than supported

[image]

Comment: Please check `length of username` and `your incorrect password` and remember to `run as Administrator` when running Stack Builder, to make sure you have privilege to create new user on Window .To get more info, please read http://www.enterprisedb.com/resources-community/tutorials-quickstarts/all-platforms/how-setup-pgagent-postgres-plus

Answer (score -2):

You should specify

System **username**

System **password**

e.g. username and password one of the windows account